# How do I get the body that was sent? Using gin gonic

Tags: go, go-gin

How do I get the body that was sent?

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)
func main()  {
  fmt.Println("Hello, world!")
  r := gin.Default()
  r.POST("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
    body := c.Request.Body
    c.JSON(200,body);
  })
  r.Run(":8080");
}
```

I make a request via postman

```
  {
         "email": "test@gmail.com",
         "password": "test"
    }
```

and in response I get empty json {}
what to do?

Comment: `Request.Body` is an `io.Reader`. It has no public fields, so there is nothing for `json` to encode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind the incoming request json as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type LoginReq struct {
    Email    string
    Password string
}

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    r.POST("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        var req LoginReq
        c.BindJSON(&req)
        c.JSON(200, req)
    })
    r.Run(":8080")
}
```

Remember this method gives `400` if there is a binding error. If you want to handle error yourself, try `ShouldBindJSON` which returns an error if any or `nil`.